# If a theory over a vocabulary $L$ has a model with countable domain, then it has a model with uncountable domain

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

For a homework I have been ask to prove that if a theory $\Sigma$ over a vocabulary $L$ has a model with countable domain, then  $\Sigma$ has a model with uncountable domain.

I have no idea how to proceed, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably "countable" means "countable *and infinite*?"

Comment: Yes its countable and infinite

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Add to the theory uncountably many new constant letters, plus axioms stating that they are pairwise different. Now use compactness.