# Proof that given an empty vocabulary, P = { $\Omega$ $\in$ STRUCT[L] | $\Omega$ has domain countable and infinity} is not definable.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Hi there i would like to prove this:

Given an empty vocabulary L ( by empty I mean L = $\emptyset$),

the property P =  { $\Omega$ $\in$ STRUCT[L] | $\Omega$ has domain countable and infinity} is not definable.

where STRUCT[L]is a set with all the possibles structures that satisfies L

Given that by definable I mean that exists a set of formulas that describes the property. Moreover the set must contain a finite number of elements.

If any one could give a hint of how to solve this i would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a direct consequence of the upwards Löwenheim–Skolem theorem. Is that what you're trying to prove it for?

Comment: I do not know what the upwards Löwenheim–Skolem theorem is but i guess i can use, what is it and how could i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) states:

> If $\Omega$ is an infinite structure over a language $L$ then for every cardinal $\lambda\ge\max(|\Omega|,|L|)$ there is a structure $\Omega'$ of cardinality $\lambda$ that is an *elementary extension* of $\Omega$ -- that it, it satisfies exactly the same first-order *$L$-sentences* as $\Omega$ does.

This means that there cannot be any (finite or infinite) set of axioms that pinpoint exactly the countably infinite $L$-structures.

Namely, whenever you have some axioms that are satisfied by *one* countably infinite $L$-structure, the upward Löwenheim-Skolem gives you an uncountable structure that also satisfies the axioms.

This is in particular the case where $L=\varnothing$.

---

Alternatively, use the answer to [If a theory over a vocabulary L has a model with countable domain, then it has a model with uncountable domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330151/if-a-theory-over-a-vocabulary-l-has-a-model-with-countable-domain-then-it-has).